# Reset jumper on Toshiba Satellite c55-a-100

Tags: laptop, motherboard, bios, toshiba-laptop, jumper

My laptop suddenly asked for bios password, not sure why.
Anyway searched for hours online to find where the jumper is to no avail.

I know my Toshiba Satellite c55-a-100 has one as the chap said that it wouldn't cost much as they only needed to reset bios with the jumper.

Where can I find a diagram of the motherboard?

Comment: Which "chap" told you this?  Is this a Boot password, or a BIOS access password?  IME, Toshiba BIOS-level passwords can't be removed by simply resetting the BIOS.  You should probably contact Toshiba for further instruction.

Comment: Agree with @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007. I have also never seen any easy BIOS password reset, otherwise defeating the purpose. Time to contact Toshiba.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

1. Dissasemble the laptop
2. Clip jumper wire to ground on motherboard (usually find this around a chassis screw hole)
3. clip a paperclip to the other end of the jumper wire
4. Run the paper clip across all the pins on the eeprom chip. (just run it over any chip you suspect it may be)
5. Reasemble the Laptop

Thats it your done if you did it correctly you will have reset the chip clearing the passwords and the computer will start up and go into bios or windows as long as there is no hdd password as well

(also this is obvious but make sure you have no power or battery supplied to the mother board while doing this)

[source](http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/questions/toshiba-bios-password-solution-for-centrino-p4-laptops/)

Comment: I think I will take it apart and have a thorough look but thank you for all the responses

Comment: Let us know how it goes.